# Reportviewer binding from Mysql dataset?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I viewed alot of existing questions but my problem is still remaining.

I have added `reportViewer1` on `MaisVendido.Form`, and also added `Report3.rdlc` in application, but this `reportviewer` is showing nothing. Why is this happening?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using System.Collections;

namespace Fabrication
{
    public partial class MaisVendido : Form
    {
        DB db = new DB();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public MaisVendido()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Getdataset();
            Getdatatable();
        }
        void Getdataset()
        {
            ds = db.ClientTable("select * from estoque");
        }
        void Getdatatable()
        {
            dt = db.Maisvendendo("select * from estoque");
        }
        private void MaisVendido_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
                reportViewer1.Visible = true;
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report3.rdlc";
                ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("Estoque", dt);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
//in my db class i have dataset and datatable two fucnitons
public DataSet ClientTable( string query )
        {
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MysqlConnect());
            con.Open();

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                ad.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
        }
public DataTable Maisvendendo( String query )
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MysqlConnect());
            con.Open();

            MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            ad.Fill(dt);
            dt.TableName = "Estoque";
            con.Close();
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: by adding Dataset and datatable from AddItem i am succeeded to show report.rdlc in reportwiever but i want pass manually dataset to report3.rdlc and want show in Reportviewer so i could not do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ReportPath in place of ReportEmbeddedResource, since you are not using an embedded resource, but a local file.

Comment: Are you switching from a report to another, or setting up one? If you are switching you need to Reset the viewer first.

Comment: Please try to review this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15597/Using-the-ASP-NET-2-0-ReportViewer-in-Local-Mode
If you still cannot handle the problem, let me know and I will help you.

Comment: Sir Manually i added one DataSset along with DataTable and by written query in add-query with configuration and adding table by toolbox on roport3.rdlc i  succeeded to show rdlc in reportviewer perfectly . but i don't want add data-set nor data-table by AddItems all work i want dynamically and then i want that DataSet or DataTable set on report3.rdlc and then want that rdlc in reportViewer but my problem i already made one DataSet and Datatalbe but i dont know how to pass this Datatale to report3.rdlc manually for showing in reportViewr help in this matter sir

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778844/how-to-bind-datatable-to-reportviewer-runtime/15831499#15831499