# How to bind datatable to reportviewer runtime

Tags: mysql, winforms, c#-4.0, data-binding, reportviewer

I want to do a bind **datatable** to **reportviewer** with the code below. I don't see the results appear in the **reportviewer**, what the lack of script below?

```
// create dataset
DataSet ds = new DataSet("myDataset");

// create datatable
DataTable dt = new DataTable("myDatatable");

// add columns
dt.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("column2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("column3", typeof(string));

// insert data rows
dt.Rows.Add("row1-col1", "row1-col2", "row1-col3");
dt.Rows.Add("row2-col1", "row2-col2", "row2-col3");

// add datatable to dataset 
ds.Tables.Add(dt);

// bind datatable to report viewer
this.reportViewer.Reset();
this.reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Test.Report1.rdlc";
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt));
this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: You have this tagged with winforms but with c#-4.0 - is this an ASP.NET app? If so can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I found the answer how to bind datatable to reportviewer,
>   I will shared here may be useful for others.
>
> 1. Add to form **clsTables class**, **Report1.rdlc file**, **reportViewer1**.
> 2. Then Click on the upper right corner of the **reportViewer1**, set **choose report** to **Test.Report1.rdlc**.
> 3. On Report1.rdlc
>
>    - Click **New**,
>    - Add **dataset name**: dsBody
>        **Data source**: Test
>        **Available dataset**: clsTables
>    - Click **Ok**
>    - Right click on Report1.rdlc select **Insert Table**, drag dsBody element(**Column0, Colum1, Column2**) to **Report1.rdlc table**.

```
Namespace Test{
    public class clsTables {
        // constructor
        public clsTables(string col0, string col1, string col2) {
            this.Column0= col0;
            this.Column1= col1;
            this.Column2= col2;
        }

       // properties
       public string Column0{ get; set; }
       public string Column1{ get; set; }
       public string Column2{ get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Test{
    public class clsMain{
        public void BindToRepprtViewer() {        
            // create dataset
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("myDataset");

            // create datatable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("myDatatable");

            // add columns
            dt.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("column2", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("column3", typeof(string));

            // insert data rows
            dt.Rows.Add("row1-col1", "row1-col2", "row1-col3");
            dt.Rows.Add("row2-col1", "row2-col2", "row2-col3");

            // add datatable to dataset 
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            // save rows to rowList 
            List<clsTables> rowList = new List<clsTables>();
            rowList .Clear();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
                rList.Add(new clsTables(Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[0]), row.ItemArray[1].ToString(), row.ItemArray[2].ToString()));
            }

            // binding rowList to bs
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = rowList;

            // binding bs to rds
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
            rds.Name = "dsBody";
            rds.Value = bs;

            // binding rds to report viewer
            reportViewer1.Reset();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource =  "Test.Report1.rdlc";
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A few bugs, and bit confusing, but it helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

The only things that I do differently is I do a:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
```

before setting the data source, and I do a:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

instead of calling RefreshReport() on the reportviewer control.

I'm not sure what the **ReportEmbeddedResource** properly does, maybe try getting rid of that too.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you might be loading in the RDLC file incorrectly. Does the report itself appear on your screen (eg just the header) or is it completely empty?

Comment: only header is visible, the data table doesn't appear printed on the report.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem, and none of the answers I found from Googling did anything for me. Finally, I  got it working. Here's the steps I followed:

1. Add a new DataSet to your project (i.e. `MyDataSet`).
2. Add a new DataTable to this DataSet (`MyDataTable`).
3. Add your columns, and set their types.
4. Add a new Report to your project (`Report1.rdlc`).
5. Add a table to the report and add the columns from MyDataSet.
6. Add a new ReportViewer object to your form (`reportViewer`).
7. Click the arrow at the top right and choose `Report1.rdlc`. This will automatically add the DataSet and a BindingSource to your form.
8. Do the following in your form load event (or where ever makes sense):

```cs
MyDataSetBindingSource.DataSource = GetDataTable();
reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Make sure the column names in your DataTable matches the ones you defined in MyDataTable.