# Create Reporting with Dataset C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datatable, report

I'm trying to create a report, but always when I execute the report I get "Missing value for parameter 'Col1'". Anyone could help me, it's my first time to create a report.

Here is my datatable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("NewDataTable");
dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
dt.Columns.Add("Col2");
dt.Rows.Add("Row1 Col1","Row1 Col2");
dt.Rows.Add("Row2 Col1","Row2 Col2");
```

Here is my report code:

```
reportViewer1.Reset();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"D:\Report\Report1.rdlc";
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("NewDataSet", dt);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Here is my report design:

[image]

Col1 and Col2 type is Text

Thanks !

Comment: Are you asking the user for 2 parameters that will be stored in Col1 and Col2? Only use parameters when requesting the user to enter data that you will then use in your queries

Comment: I just want to show the parameters that was send by dt ! I don't want to ask something to user. I want to show "Row1 Col1" and "Row1 Col2" in my report !

Comment: I don't see anything you are providing that requires parameters so you are getting the error they are missing because they aren't provided.

Comment: Could be ! I dont know how to create report ! What I have to create in the report to show my information ? Thank you about your help !

Comment: look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778844/how-to-bind-datatable-to-reportviewer-runtime