# Display DataTable content in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I've heard that the best way to print a **DataTable** is to use **ReportViewer**. However I found it more difficult to achieve this than I thought. I am not familiar with ReportViewer, so perhaps I want to find a solution that is non-existent.

"reportView" is the ReportViewer control.

```
//I am creating a fresh new DataTable here.
DataTable reportDT = new DataTable();
reportDT.TableName = "reportDT";
DataColumn dataColID = reportDT.Columns.Add("ID");
DataColumn dataColValue = reportDT.Columns.Add("Value");
DataRow newrow = reportDT.NewRow();
newrow["ID"] = string1;
newrow["Value"] = string2;
reportDT.Rows.Add(newrow);
//Until now, this works perfectly with DataGridView.
//I am creating a new source object, hopefully from my datatable.
ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("reportDT", reportDT);
reportView.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportView.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
this.reportView.RefreshReport();
```

Running the app like this throws no exception, but it shows no data in the reportview either. It says: "The source of the report definition has not been specified".
I have realized that it might need a .rdlc file, which must be created design time. But if I create it design time, it wants me to fill it with data, which I cannot do, because the data is created runtime. So I want to display a bunch of data in ReportViewer, but the above code does not work. What is wrong with it?

Comment: How are you loading `reportView` `ReportViewer` object?

Comment: What do you mean? I placed the control in the designer, which runs when the form containing the control loads. The rest of the code is above (that runs on form creation aswell).

Comment: Is your overall goal here to get the data from the DataTable displayed to the user?

Why not use a DataGridView?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a report file. The `reportViewer1` is a `Control`, not a `Report` and therefore cannot display data directly.

To avoid repeating code, your answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778844/how-to-bind-datatable-to-reportviewer-runtime).