# Reportview asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I added to my project (asp.net + MySQL) one Report.rdlc file and does not include data source and dataset. The rdlc file has not been set yet.
I want to use a DataTable in the generation of reports.
I put a component "table" but has not as dataset or datasource can not configure the report structure. I'm having problems with ODBC drive for VS 2013 and do not want to use it. I wonder if the code below is suitable for generating the report:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(util.getStringConection());
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from user", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);

        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        LocalReport lr = ReportViewer1.LocalReport;
        lr.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("rds", dt);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
}
```

I need only display a list of users who are registered.

Comment: `what do you mean you want to know if the code below is suitable for generating the report..?` what happens when you run/execute the code..?
also what happens `if(IsPostBack)` is true.. how are you handling the rebinding of the data to be viewed in the web page..? use the debugger to step through the code as well to pinpoint any issue if any..with the existing code that you have posted

Comment: @MethodMan, I put a breakpoint in the running and no error occurs but does not return any results ... if I remove the line "if (! IsPostBack)", is an infinite loop and no results are displayed. The sql instruciton it's ok. The way it is not showing any results

Comment: ok break it down and first when you put a breakpoint at this line `ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;` and look ant the `dt` variable in DataVisualizer, is there any data returned..? also is the connection string configured correctly..? what if you run `Select * from user` out side of the application does it return data..?

Comment: you are missing the following it looks like `.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report.rdlc"` take a look here and change your code to how the accepted answer has it on this SO post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778844/how-to-bind-datatable-to-reportviewer-runtime also in the future .. do a quick `Google Search`